# Median of given range of elements in a binary search tree

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Given a range [l, r], we are supposed to find the median of all the nodes that are present in the binary search tree and whose values are within l and r.
Let me take an example. 
Let the BST be the following

```
     7 
   /   \
  3     12
 / \   /  \
2   5 10   15
```

and let the range be [1, 14]. Now we see that the nodes we have that fall within the range are [2, 3, 5, 7, 10 and 12]. The median of this list is (7 + 5) / 2 = 6.
What is the complexity of the most efficient algorithm?
**Ideas** 
I have seen a similar problem that is the complexity of reporting elements that fall within the range [l, r]. The complexity is O(logn + k) where k is the number of elements in the BST that fall within the range, (assuming O(logn) as the cost of finding the first element that falls in the range given the BST is a balanced one). Then, given we have these elements that fall within the range, calculating their median would then incur O(k) additional cost giving the complexity to be O(logn + k). Is there a better algorithm, or is my thinking flawed? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: At every node, store the count of the number of nodes in its subtree. That might give $O(\log n)$ time.